# Minimization problem, both terms in function positive

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following problem:
Using the simplex method, minimize $z = 10x + 3y$ given the following conditions: 
$$2x + y \le 12$$
$$4x + y \ge 12$$
$$2x + y \ge 8$$

I've been told that minimizing $z$ is the same thing as maximizing $-z$, which means I shall maximize $z = -10x - 3y$, which can be re-written as $z + 10x + 3y = 0$. But since all coefficients are positive, it appears to me that the problem is already solved - namely, that the minimum value of $z$ is $0$ - but it isn't, because $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ is not defined. How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Since there are only two decision variables, you can draw the feasible region, identify the extreme points, and evaluate the objective value at each point. By the way, do you have $x,y\geqslant 0$ or not?

Comment: I can, but I'm not allowed to. x,y >= 0 is not given.

Comment: I think you have to use the Simplex method?

Answer (score 0):

1- Compute the minimum of your problem by derivating $f(x,y)=10x+3y$

2- Evaluat the minimum value you can have of the edges

3- Take the best solution

For more details [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkzsxvucLjQ)

Answer (score 0):

We basically should just consider the intersection points (a principle of linear programming). Please tell me if you want me to explain this in detail.

$2x+y=12$ and $4x+y=12$ intersect at $x=0$, $y=12$ (subtract the first equation off the second and the solve for $y$ using the first.

$4x+y=12$ and $2x+y=8$ intersect at $x=2$, $y=4$. (subtract the second equation off the first and then solve for $y$ using the second)

We have to grasp this first: we basically are bounded by $2$ sets of parallel lines, and another line, so the other set will not have any intersection.

By that principle, we have to see if it is unbounded, its max at $(0,12)$ or at $(2,4)$. However it is clearly not unbounded because we can show that if we go down while keeping the same distance from the boundaries, the value of $10x+3y$ will also go down. (the slope of $2x+y$ is $-2$), while the slope of $10x+3y$ is $-\frac{10}. {3}$. Hence it maximum is bounded.

$10x+3y$ at $(0,12)$ gives $36$, while at $(2,4) gives $32$.

Hence its maximum is $36$ at $(0,12)$.